# How can I set the x-axis to date applying mutliplotyyy?

Tags: matlab, datetime

I am trying to plot three time series with different temporal resolution into one graph applying [multiplotyyy](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39595-multiplotyyy). Unfortunately, I cannot set the x-axis to datetick. Any idea how to solve that? Thanks!

The applied approach is based on [datetime matlab different temporal resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55017690/datetime-matlab-different-temporal-resolution/55019358#55019358) for one plot with two axis, which works quiet well.

```
%time 5min interval for dataset1
xstart1 = datenum('01/04 10:00', 'dd/mm HH:MM');
xend1 = datenum('02/04 14:00', 'dd/mm HH:MM');
Dat1 = xstart1:1/24/12:xend1;


%time 10min interval for dataset2 and dataset3
xstart2 = datenum('01/04 13:00', 'dd/mm HH:MM'); 
xend2 = datenum('02/04 14:00', 'dd/mm HH:MM');
Dat2 = xstart2:1/24/6:xend2;

%time axis (different temporal resolution)
Dat = xstart1:1/12:xend1;

%data
dataset1 = rand(1,337).';
dataset2 = rand(1,151).';
dataset3 = rand(1,151).';

%plot
ylabels{1}='dataset1';
ylabels{2}='dataset2';
ylabels{3}='dataset3';
[ax,hlines]=multiplotyyy({Dat2, dataset2}, {Dat2, dataset3}, {Dat1, dataset1}, ylabels);
set(ax(1), 'XTick', Dat);
datetick('x', 'dd/mm HH:MM', 'keepticks', 'keeplimits');
legend(cat(1,hlines{:}),'dataset1','dataset2','dataset3','location','w')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem

Read the documentation of [datenum](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

> The datenum function creates a numeric array that represents each point in time as the number of days from January 0, 0000.

Values of `Dat` are very large numbers.

I assume you want the `XTick` labels to be in date format, and not is seconds since BC.

Use [datestr](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) for converting `Dat` to the desired format, and convert it to cell array.
(After the line `Dat = xstart1:1/12:xend1;`)
Use the following (`'hh/mm'` is just an example format):

```
DateStr = cellstr(datestr(Dat, 'hh/mm'));
```

Set `XTickLabel` after setting `XTick`:

```
set(ax(1), 'XTick', Dat);
set(ax(1), 'XTickLabel', DateStr);
```

Result:
[image: Tick]

Comment: Thanks for this fast reply! I do have the time on the x-axis now with your suggestion. However, I do not have a tick every two hours as I originally aimed, so the line __Dat=xstart1:1/12:xend1;__ does not work properly anymore. Why is that the case?

Comment: I honesty don't know. According to the documentation it was not supposed to work.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a tick every two hours?

Comment: Try setting both `set(ax(1), 'XTick', Dat);` and `set(ax(1), 'XTickLabel', DateStr);`.

Comment: You may also try: `set(ax(1), 'TickLength', [0.02,0.025]);` to make ticks longer. And `set(ax(1), 'LineWidth', 2);` to make them thicker.